# How to read code of test case kept in QC?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to read the code written inside test case made in QTP and which is kept in QC.
So my requirement is:

1. Connect QC.
2. Reach to the particular test case by specifying its path in QC.
3. Try to read the code written inside test case as we read simple text file using filesystemobject in similar manner.

I know how to read code in test case, see below code

```
filename = "C:\YourUFTTest\Action1\script.mts"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  MsgBox f.ReadLine
Loop

f.Close
```

But the requirement now is different.

I need to read the code of test case which is kept in QC.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code will help you.

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtApp.TDConnection.Connect "http://xyz/qcbin/", "domain", "project", "used", "Password", False 

If qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected then
  msgbox "connected"
  qtApp.Open "[QualityCenter] Subject\..\..\Testname",True
  qtApp.Test.SaveAs "C:\path\Test1"
Else    
    msgbox "not connected"
End if
Set qtApp = Nothing
```

After downloading the script, read the script using FSO object like written above